# Can't add NSDictionary to NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to add an dictionary to an array to create an array on dictionaries, but when I test the app, the array is still empty. Take a look on my code:

```
NSMutableArray *listaEstabelecimentosPorCategoria;


    for (NSDictionary *tempDict in listaEstabelecimentos) {

        if ([[tempDict objectForKey:@"category"] integerValue] == 1) {
            [listaEstabelecimentosPorCategoria addObject:tempDict];

            NSLog(@"TEST");
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", listaEstabelecimentosPorCategoria);
```

The app prints this:

```
2013-08-18 12:16:38.802 Petrópolis[10157:c07] TEST
2013-08-18 12:16:38.802 Petrópolis[10157:c07] TEST
2013-08-18 12:16:38.803 Petrópolis[10157:c07] (null)
```

Comment: You forgot to initialize your array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> when I test the app, the array is still empty.

This is because you did not initialize `listaEstabelecimentosPorCategoria`:

```
NSMutableArray *listaEstabelecimentosPorCategoria = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSMutableArray *listaEstabelecimentosPorCategoria=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //initialize


for (NSDictionary *tempDict in listaEstabelecimentos) {

    if ([[tempDict objectForKey:@"category"] integerValue] == 1) {
        [listaEstabelecimentosPorCategoria addObject:tempDict];

        NSLog(@"TEST");
    }
}

NSLog(@"%@", listaEstabelecimentosPorCategoria);
```

Comment: You forgot an extra bracket before NSMutableArray

Answer (score -1):

`NSMutableArray *listaEstabelecimentosPorCategoria` this code hasn't been allocated to memory so it will be null value

```
NSMutableArray *listaEstabelecimentosPorCategoria = [NSMutableArray array];
```

then `listaEstabelecimentosPorCategoria` add the object.